# Click a <td> element to cause a self posting event with an SQL query involving multiple tables. PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

What I have is a table that is pulled from a database. The goal is that I want to be able to click on any team and have a self posted page produce a table with previous yearly results per row (multiple tables, year by year) and a row of total stats. For example: Click on San Jose and get 2014-2015 stats in 1 row, 2015-2016 in the next row and then a total of all the seasons added up. Not really sure how to implement it. I would love to get some suggestions on the best way to attack this problem. 
[Link To My Project](http://52.4.65.161/final_project/standings.php?standingsYear=2015_2016&standingsType=conference) 
Here is some of my code, so you can see how I am doing it so far.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM standings2015_2016 WHERE confid='2' ORDER BY pts DESC, losses ASC, otl ASC, gf-ga DESC";
        $result = $db->query($query);
        echo "<h3>Western Conference</h3>";
        echo "<table class='table sortable'>";  
        echo "<tr class='TableHeaders'>";
        echo "<td class='hover'>Place</td>";
        echo "<td class='hover'>Team</td>";
        echo "<td class='hover'>Wins</td>";
        echo "<td class='hover'>Losses</td>";
        echo "<td class='hover'>OTL</td>";
        echo "<td class='hover'>Points</td>";
        echo "<td class='hover'>GF</td>";
        echo "<td class='hover'>GA</td>";
        echo "<td class='hover'>+ / -</td>";
        echo "</tr>";   

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($result as $row) {
        $i++;
        $plusMinus = ($row['gf'] - $row['ga']); 
          echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $i;
            echo "</td><td class='hover2'>";
            echo stripslashes($row['name']); 
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo stripslashes($row['wins']);
            echo "</td><td>";    
            echo stripslashes($row['losses']);  
            echo "</td><td>";    
            echo stripslashes($row['otl']); 
            echo "</td><td>";    
            echo stripslashes($row['pts']);
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo stripslashes($row['gf']);
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo stripslashes($row['ga']);
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $plusMinus;
            echo "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
          }
        echo "</table>";
```

So `echo stripslashes($row['name']);` is the team name I want to click on. Can this be done with an onclick event to prompt a query and a self post?

Comment: You want to show the data/stats in a modal? Without leaving the page when clicked?

Comment: We need the definition of your database if you want the SQL query as well.

Comment: Is modal a different window? If so, no. I would like it to just display in the content div where I have my table, but by it's self (no other teams visible) . If you change around the filter and year with the drop downs and submit, I would like it to act like that, but with just that particular team. It does not have to be a form necessarily, but I am not familiar with AJAX and I am not well versed in Javascript either.

Comment: But you need to use AJAX and javascript in order for it to return data into your content div without refreshing the page. How do you get the stat for a team anyway? Your table structure for getting the stats?

Comment: Kelvin Lai: `CREATE TABLE "standings2014_2015" ('teamid' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 'confid' INTEGER, 'divid' INTEGER, 'name' TEXT, 'wins' INTEGER, 'losses' INTEGER, 'otl' INTEGER, 'pts' INTEGER, 'gf' INTEGER, 'ga' INTEGER)` The standings2015_2016 table is the same

Comment: So, there are two tables that stores the standings of each team? And when a team is selected/clicked, its 2014-2015 and 2015-2016 standings will be shown to your content div?

Comment: Refreshing the page is not really a concern for me. That would be an added bonus to avoid refreshing a page. I was more against the idea of creating an entirely new php file for this process.

Comment: "So, there are two tables that stores the standings of each team? And when a team is selected/clicked, its 2014-2015 and 2015-2016 standings will be shown to your content div?" Correct, and then I would have a 3rd column to add up everything. Which I could do myself without help.

Comment: @KurtLeadley - I'm assuming that the `teamid` column of your `standings2014_2015` is the same with the `teamid` for `standings2015_2016`? For example, Vancouver's ID is 15 in both tables? I'm processing my answer now.

Comment: @Logan Wayne Correct. The standings are actually scraped from this link and I have last season saved to my DB http://www.tsn.ca/datafiles/XML/NHL/standings.xml The current season is also just "updated" to the current seasons table.

Comment: If you want to only use php you can create a new page to display only the result from the team you want. However, if you do not want to move from the page you will have to use javascript. So just to be sure, when you click on the NHL team, you want to display the standings from that year and previous year, correct?

Comment: @VictorLuna - I want it to be at least self posting. I don't want 30 extra php files for each team to be displayed. As for your last question, yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you want, we can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

First is to download jQuery [here](https://jquery.com/download/).

Then create a link element for each team name that has `class` and `data-artid` tag:

```
echo '<a href="#" class="teamname" data-artid="'.$row["teamid"].'">'.stripslashes($row['name']).'</a>';
```

Then create the script:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!-- REPLACE NECESSARY JQUERY FILE DEPENDING ON THE VERSION YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */
    $(".teamname").click(function(){ /* WHEN A TEAM IS CLICKED */
      var elem = $(this); /* STORE THE CLICKED TEAM */
      var teamid = elem.attr("data-artid"); /* GET THE ID OF THE CLICKED TEAM NAME */

      $.ajax({ /* PREPARE THE AJAX */
        type: "POST", /* METHOD TO BE USED TO PROCESS THE PASSED DATA */
        url: "action.php", /* THE PAGE WHERE THE DATA WILL BE PROCESSED */
        data: {"teamid": teamid}, /* THE DATA WE WILL PASS */
        success: function(result){
          $("#content").html(result); /* WE WILL SHOW THE RETURNED DATA TO YOUR CONTENT DIV */
        } /* END OF SUCCESS */

      }); /* END OF AJAX */
    });
  });

</script>
```

And for your action.php, which will process the passed on data using Ajax:

```
<?php

  /* INCLUDE YOUR DB CONNECTION HERE */

  if(!empty($_POST["teamid"])){

    $tr = '
          <table class="table sortable">
            <tr class="TableHeaders">
              <td class="hover">Team</td>
              <td class="hover">Wins</td>
              <td class="hover">Losses</td>
              <td class="hover">OTL</td>
              <td class="hover">Points</td>
              <td class="hover">GF</td>
              <td class="hover">GA</td>
            </tr>
          ';

    $result = $db->query("SELECT name, wins, losses, otl, pts, gf, ga FROM standings2014_2015 WHERE teamid = '".$_POST["teamid"]."'");
    foreach ($result as $row) {
      $tr .= '
             <tr>
               <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
               <td>'.$row["wins"].'</td>
               <td>'.$row["losses"].'</td>
               <td>'.$row["otl"].'</td>
               <td>'.$row["pts"].'</td>
               <td>'.$row["gf"].'</td>
               <td>'.$row["ga"].'</td>
             </tr>
             ';
    } /* END OF LOOP */

    $tr .= '</table>';

    echo $tr; /* RETURN THIS TO AJAX */

  } /* END OF NOT EMPTY teamid */

?>
```

Comment: Hmm, I must be missing something because nothing is happening when I click a team name after doing those 3 things.

Comment: http://52.4.65.161/final_project/standings.php The team names are links though. I know jquery is activated because I am using it to validate my drop down boxes.

Comment: What is the error? You can see it in your console. If you are using Chrome, hit F12.

Comment: if(!empty($_POST["teamid"])){ ....}   It is not getting this post because I can echo outside this if statement.

Comment: There is no error, it just isn't getting the POST. I tried GET also, since I was using GET for everything else. No avail.

Comment: Did you create an extra file, action.php?

Comment: Yes. and it prints "Test" outside of the if test

Comment: Did you include your db connection in action.php? And don't use GET, return it to POST because that is what we use in our AJAX `type: "POST",`.

Comment: At one point I tried an include on my header, which connects to the db

Comment: My mistake, updated my answer. Check the `var teamid = elem.attr("data-artid");` instead of `var teamid = elem.val();`

Comment: Here is action.php in the same directory as my other files so DB connections should be fine...Note that only "TEST" echo's http://codeshare.io/ZWfP3

Comment: After updating, clicking the linked names does nothing now.

Comment: I checked your code, because you establish your connection using PDO API, so check again my answer and re-establish a new one just for that.

Comment: Here is the console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Check my answer again. I used a `mysqli_*` prepared statement for action.php, where you are using a PDO to establish your connection. And I don't see where you included the jQuery file - `<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: "I checked your code, because you establish your connection using PDO API, so check again my answer and re-establish a new one just for that." I don't understand. You want me to connect to a SQLite server with a MySQLi statement? I thought that was impossible. I have:  `try {   
   $db = new PDO('sqlite:../../SharksDB/SharksDB');  
   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
  } catch (Exception $e) {  
    echo "Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.";
    exit;
   }` In action.php right now

Comment: The jquery is included in a header file

Comment: Updated my answer. Didn't know you are using SQLite. I just use your code on how you fetch data from your database.

Comment: I use this for everything, and it won't work in action.php `try {   
   $db = new PDO('sqlite:../../SharksDB/SharksDB');  
   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
  } catch (Exception $e) {  
    echo "Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.";
    exit;
   }` Same directory too

Comment: I also apologize for not mentioning PDO.

Comment: Can you update your codeshare? So I can take a look.

Comment: action.php http://codeshare.io/ZWfP3 standings.php http://codeshare.io/aOL1x header.php http://codeshare.io/E0Ysj and my website http://52.4.65.161/final_project/standings.php

Comment: Ahh.. You did not update the action.php. I changed it earlier actually, take a look again at my code. Remove also the `echo "TEST";`

Comment: I stopped at the PDO part, my bad! Go try out Montreal real quick. I think I am on my way!

Comment: @KurtLeadley - just a little further. Updated my answer, take a look. Forgot to add `<table>`.

Comment: = ) Thank you. Hope you had fun doing this.

Comment: Sure. No problem. Goodluck!

Comment: I'll post ya a link when I get it all sorted out  = )

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an ID to each one of the teams in your database and then use that ID to pull the information in one php file. In that file you can just get the ID perform the query search and display the information in a different page.

In the index.php where you display all the teams you can add a link to the team.php.

```
 echo "<a href=\"team.php?Id=".$team['Id']."\">";
```

team.php

```
    if (isset($_GET['Id']) && is_numeric($_GET['Id'])) 
    {
    // Perform database query
    $teamID = mysql_escape_string($_GET['Id']);

    // Assign the query to a variable
    $query = "SELECT name, wins, losses, otl, pts, gf, ga FROM standings2014_2015 WHERE Id=".$teamID.";";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    // If the user exists
    if ($result) 
    {
    while ($team = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
       echo $team["name"];
       echo $team["wins"];
       ....
// Display the information in the table
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this code:

For standings.php modify this:

```
 echo stripslashes($row['name']);
```

by:

```
 echo "<a href=\"standings.php?name=".stripslashes($row['name'])."\">";
```

Then  standings.php should view like this:

```
    if (isset($_GET['name']) && !is_empty($_GET['name'])) 
    {

    $kname = mysql_escape_string($_GET['name']);

    $query = "SELECT name, wins, losses, otl, pts, gf, ga FROM standings2014_2015 WHERE name=".$kname.";";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    if ($result) 
    {  echo "<table class='table sortable'>";  
       foreach ($result as $row) 
       {
         $tr .= '
           <tr>
             <td>'.$name.'</td>
             <td>'.$wins.'</td>
             <td>'.$losses.'</td>
             <td>'.$otl.'</td>
             <td>'.$pts.'</td>
             <td>'.$gf.'</td>
             <td>'.$ga.'</td>
           </tr>
           ';
         echo $tr;

       }
       echo "</table>";  
    }

   }else{ 
     //YOUR ACTUAL CODE
   }
```